# Do these produce the same output?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm confused by an exercise on the mooc.fi Java course. My solution apparently produces the same output as the provided solution, but my solution requires more code. I don't understand how their solution works. Is there a mistake in their solution? How does the logic in their if statement work?

My solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give a year: ");
        int year = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        boolean bool = year % 100 == 0 && year % 4 == 0;
        if (bool == true) {
            if (year % 400 == 0) {
                System.out.println("This year is a leap year.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("This year is not a leap year.");
            }

        } else if (bool == false && year % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println("This year is a leap year.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This year is not a leap year.");
        }

    }
}
```

and their solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class LeapYear {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        System.out.print("Give a year: ");
        int year = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("The year is a leap year.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The year is not a leap year.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code from the course has fewer lines because they've specified the condition in one expression rather than relying on multiple `if` statements. As an aside, you don't need to compare a boolean variable to `true` or `false` to use it in an `if` statement: `if (bool)` or `if (!bool)` would suffice.

Comment: all they have done is just simplified the code with a better logic

Comment: There are 2 possible outcomes: a year is a leap year, or not. So it can be expressed in a single `if`. You check `year % 4 == 0` twice, btw.

Comment: A good tip for beginner programmers: assume that the mistake is with *your* code, not with others'. You'll be right 99.99% of the time.

Comment: Note: the proper way to check boolean vars is simply `if (thatBool)` . And: use meaningful names. The **type** of your boolean variable is clear, there is no point in naming it `bool`. Use a name that says what it is ABOUT, like `isLeapYear`.

Comment: @tevemadar it can't, there are several other criteria. 1900 was no leap year because of one of them, 2000 was because of another, 2100 again won't be.

Answer (score 2):

Your program apparently arrives at the same output - but its logic is a bit awkward.

Take a look a this, for example:

```java
boolean bool = year % 100 == 0 && year % 4 == 0;
```

So it's supposed to be true when the year is divisible by 100 as well as by 4. But mathematically, any year that is divisible by 100 is also divisible by 4. That's because

```
year = N * 100
```

is the same as

```
year = N * 25 * 4
```

So what your "bool" actually represents is "isDivisibleBy100".

So your code basically says:

```
if the year is divisible by 100
    if it is divisible by 400
       it is leap
    otherwise
       it is not leap
otherwise
    if it is divisible by 4
       it is leap
    otherwise
       it is not leap
```

Which is quite a verbose way to say the actual rule of leap years, which is - a year is leap if it is divisible by 4 but not by 100, except when divisible by 400, where it is leap.

This means, any year that is not divisible by 4 is never ever leap, no exception.

Of the years that are divisible by 4, only ones that are not divisible by 100 are leap - except if they are divisible by 400.

Which iis the same as saying:

"Of the years that are divisible by 4, only ones that are either not divisible by 100 or are divisible by 400 are leap. All the others are not leap"

Which is exactly what their code says:

```java
 if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) {
     System.out.println("The year is a leap year.");
 } else {
     System.out.println("The year is not a leap year.");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does the logic in their if statement work?

The condition used in the tutorial code

```
year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)
```

can be expressed in English as:

> the year is divisible by 4, and it is either not divisible by 100 or it is divisible by 400

Comment: Yes, but according to the exercise instructions: "A year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4. However, if the year is divisible by 100, then it is a leap year only when it is also divisible by 400." How does that code output the proper result then?

Comment: @userbaseww but, what you just said is exactly equal to the above: "However, if the year is divisible by 100, then it is a leap year only when it is also divisible by 400." is the same as "and it is either not divisible by 100 or it is divisible by 400".